Set of problems or books like Kowalski Lecture notes on linear algebra.
I found this wonderful set of lecture notes on linear algebra here but it lacks problems!
I'm hoping to find something similar to these notes (with problems) or problem sets/books accompanying these notes.
I found this book Problems and theorems in linear algebra by Prasalov but they start from determinants and so.
Also, I'm not really sure if this is a duplicate as I didn't find anything similar, Eh. Thanks!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If it's problems you want, there's always the Schaum's Outline series.
